# Uncaught Error: Class Not found in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am working with plugin in wordpress.I need to use autload so I add composer.json add loader in composer.json

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "GhaziRiyadh\\ThemeSortcodes\\": "app/"
        }
    }
```

After that I add App.php in app folder:

```
<?php

namespace GhaziRiyadh\ThemeSortcodes\App;

class App
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        wp_die('from app');
    }
}
```

And I add in main file for plugin:

```
define('THEME_SHORTCODES_DIR', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__));
define('THEME_SHORTCODES_URL', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__));

require_once THEME_SHORTCODES_DIR . 'vendor/autoload.php';
use GhaziRiyadh\ThemeSortcodes\App;

new App();
```

When run this plugin get error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "GhaziRiyadh\ThemeSortcodes\App\App" not found
   in A:\wordpress\wordpress_abowab\wp-content\plugins\theme-sortcodes\theme-sortcodes.php:19
Stack trace: 
#0 A:\wordpress\wordpress_abowab\wp-settings.php(453): include_once() 
#1 A:\wordpress\wordpress_abowab\wp-config.php(98): require_once('A:\\wordpress\\wo...') 
#2 A:\wordpress\wordpress_abowab\wp-load.php(50): require_once('A:\\wordpress\\wo...') 
#3 A:\wordpress\wordpress_abowab\wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('A:\\wordpress\\wo...') 
#4 A:\wordpress\wordpress_abowab\index.php(17): require('A:\\wordpress\\wo...') 
#5 {main} 
thrown in A:\wordpress\wordpress_abowab\wp-content\plugins\theme-sortcodes\theme-sortcodes.php on line 19
```

Comment: Is the namespace `GhaziRiyadh\ThemeSortcodes\App\App;` and not `GhaziRiyadh\ThemeSortcodes\App;`?

Comment: I tryed with out App\App and still not work.